# Compute engine VM instance create with container + SSD

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-os, google-compute-disk

In the SSD guide https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-local-ssd#gcloud I need to perform some operations in the host to format the SSD. How can I do it if I immediately launch a container?

Comment: See: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/startup-scripts

Answer (score 0):

You can add your command in startup scripts for Linux.
If you are using a Windows machine, you need to give parameters in metadata and then need to specify commands or you can store the script in local and run on system reboot.